# Codeigniter PHP - loading a view at an anchor point

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I have a form at the bottom of a long page, if a user fills out the form but it doesn't validate the page is reloaded in the typical codeigniter fashion:

`$this->load->view('template',$data);`

however because the form is way down at the bottom of the page I need the page to load down there like you do with HTML anchors. Does anyone know how to do this in codeigniter?

I can't use the codeigniter

`redirect();`

function because it loses the object and the validation errors are gone. Other frameworks I've used like Yii you can call the redirect function like:

`$this->redirect();`

which solves the problem because you keep the object. I've tried using:

`$this->index()`

within the controller which works fine as a redirect but the validation errors are in another method which is where the current page is loaded from:

`$this->item($labs)`

but when I use this it get stuck in a loop

Any ideas? I've seen this question a lot on the net but no clear answers. I'm researching using codeigniter "flash data" but think it's a bit overkill.

cheers.

Comment: @"overkill" what makes you think so? IMO it is very good feature, which I guess is exactly made for things like these.

Comment: Are you open to using javascript ?

Comment: @goldenparrot maybe I was a little overkill with that statement. I have nothing against flash data but thought it could be done another way.

Comment: @aziz.punjani I'm already using javascript for validation as well but this is seperate as it's for non javascript users. cheers though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't personally vouch for this, but according to [this thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/119231/#590064) if you append the anchor to the form's `action`, it will work.

**CodeIgniter helper:**

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/function#anchor'); ?>
```

**Or vanilla HTML:**

```
<form method='post' action='controller/function#anchor'>
```

If you were open to using Javascript, you could easily detect a `$validation_failed` variable and appropriately scroll. Or, even better, use AJAX.

Another option is to put the form near the top of the page?

Comment: Nice find jordan, that worked! I didn't even try that because I was sure it wouldn't work. Codeigniter must have it built into the route controller to split any url strings with a hash "#". Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as far as I understood your problem, it isn't *much* related to the back end(codeigniter). You want the form at the bottom of the page to be 'what-users-sees-on-page-load' (since you mention anchors).

Now, what you can do is, you can set delimiters for your validation error messages using:

```
echo validation_errors('<div id="bottom_form_error">', '</div>');
```

Using [jQuery ScrollTo](http://balupton.github.com/jquery-scrollto/demo/), do:

```
$( function() { $('#bottom_form_error').ScrollTo(); } );
```

And, the user will be scrolled to the errors at the bottom of the page. Don't forget to include jQuery too.

Anchor hash fragment click is different - it is scrolling at [∞](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity) speed.

I hope that is what you wanted.

---

P.S. I am ignoring what you said below this line:

> Does anyone know how to do this in codeigniter?

as I felt it is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: The comment is related to validation. But, I think aziz really asked to know if he could use javascript to scroll. Even if aziz didn't, I think it's a valid question: does the OP want to use javascript for scrolling to the validation errors, if form's at the bottom? if yes, then here is a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks but I've got it all covered with JS. what if the user didn't have JS that was the question. In which is it's all about codeigniter reloading the page in the right place which is only achieved with an anchor tag if JS is disabled. Thanks for your help though!