# Codeigniter: Load View file with #id added on to url to scroll down page

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter, view

I am using the form validation class in codeigniter. All working fine but when it reloads the form with the errors the page is at the top again. (because it's refreshed). Is there a way I can add an `#id` onto the end of the url so it will load further down the page where the form is?

I tried `redirect('form/form#form, 'refresh')` which worked but didnt carry through the errors.

Comment: Closing as duplicate - [see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533455/codeigniter-php-loading-a-view-at-an-anchor-point/12537033#12537033)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you redirect the page then the POST array is cleared. Therefore set_value() can't repopulate your form.

There are a couple of ways you can go about this

1. Overwrite the session library. Inside this library, stick your post array into a session flash_data on redirect. Then inside your set_value functions ( there are 2 of them ), if you can't find anything in the post array, look for your flashdata.
2. Don't use the set_value function. Instead, inside your action controller put your form data into flashdata, and inside your form, use $this->session->flashdata('form_field_1'), instead of set_value('form_field_1');

As far as the redirection goes, you're doing it right.

Sorry for being lazy and not posting code. If this isn't clear enough let me know and I can post code.

Answer (score 0):

You're just doing a simple form validation right?  If so, you should be able to use set_value to repopulate your form after an error.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

If you're using CI's form validation, I'm assuming your form goes back to the controller.  The controller should then determine where to go.

```
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
      $this->load->view('form#anchor');
  } else {
      $this->load->view('formsuccess');
  }
```

You should be able to dynamically set the #anchor tag in your controller based on what errors you get during validation.